# Vue.js Routing Guard issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I got a route guard set up that check if route is for visitors (login and register routes) and if it is and user is authenticated redirect to dashboard. However this sometimes works and sometimes not.

```
router.beforeEach((to,from,next)=>{

    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forGuests)) {
        if (auth.quickCheck()) {
            console.log('should redirect now')
            next({name:'dashboard'});
        } else next()
    }
    next();
});
```

This is my guard. I always get that `console.log` message but it does not always redirect for some reason. This issue is happening when I change routes "live". Vue router is picking it up but does not redirect how it should...
This is my login route for example.

```
  {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: require('./views/Login.vue'),
      meta:{
        forGuests: true
      }
    },
```

Main issue here is that it **sometimes work !**. For example this is my console.log:

```
should redirect now
Component mounted.
should redirect now
```

Component mounted is happening when register component is mounted. As you can see first time when I changed to `/login` i got both *should redirect* and *component mounted* (and it did redirect me) and next time i got just that *should redirect* and stayed on */login*

Comment: You say : **This issue is happening when I change routes "live".**. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @user7814783 Changing the path in browser

Comment: OK now I understand. I too faced this problem. When you search for a guarded path directly in the browser's search what happens is the vue app is re-rendered(refreshed). You are using `auth.quickCheck()` to check is the user is authenticated. You are saving user's authentication status as a `var` or `object` which `true` or `false` based on whether user is logged in or not. What happens when you directly search or a route in browser's search is the `var` or `object` storing user's authentication status is set back to initial state which is `false`.

Comment: I suggest you to store the user's authentication state in a cookie. Then you can check the Cookie's value to determine if user is logged in or not. Then you don't have to worry for page refresh changing back your authentication state back to false .

Comment: @VAMSIKRISHNA Yeah that fixed it. Thanks